# HTTP POST, how to get the message body (data)

Tags: c, http, post

I am working on an embedded web server. I want to receive a POST but don't know how to access the message body (data). Is the header a fixed size? How does one normally access the message body?

Programming in C.

Edit:

I believe the answer is that there is an empty line (CRLF) between the header fields and the data. If anyone wants to confirm this, it would be appreciated. Will be testing this shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an empty line (CR+LF+CR+LF) at the end of the headers. You probably need to read the format spec (search the Internet for e.g. HTTP RFC); there are several HTTP versions so you will eventually need to know exactly what the format is.

Comment: Thanks! I have checked the RFC and I know what version I am using. Still haven't tested it yet, but I'm sure this will work. If not, I'll be back.